# wear of NVME SSD disk (Debian)

Tags: debian, ssd

On my Debian/Sid desktop home computer (AMD Ryzen 2970WX, some MSI 399 motherboard) I have an SSD M2 NVME and I am getting -to `root` - automatic mails such as:

> ```
>  The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:
>
>  Device: /dev/nvme0, number of Error Log entries increased from 423 to
>  424
>
>  Device info: Samsung SSD 970 EVO 2TB, S/N:S464NB0KA03837J,
>  FW:2B2QEXE7, 2.00 TB
>
> For details see host's SYSLOG.
> ```

That SSD disk hold the root partition (filled to 29% according to `df -h`) and `/home` (filled to 5%).

The desktop (powered on thru an UPS 24h/24, located near Paris in France) is mostly used to develop [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) and usual software developer activity (software build, debugging, tests, and mail and web browsing, LaTeX, emacs, running `./refpersys`, etc...).

## My understanding is that it is normal wearout of SSD NVME disks.

After a `smartctl --test=short /dev/nvme0` (run as root) the command `smartctl -a /dev/nvme0`  gives

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-3-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 970 EVO 2TB
Serial Number:                      S464NB0KA03837J
Firmware Version:                   2B2QEXE7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            258,943,426,560 [258 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 5a81b50e6f
Local Time is:                      Mon Feb  3 10:28:49 2020 MET
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     82 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     82 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     6.20W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.30W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     2.10W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        39 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    170,671,345 [87.3 TB]
Data Units Written:                 6,787,146 [3.47 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 1,072,794,583
Host Write Commands:                62,979,313
Controller Busy Time:               1,480
Power Cycles:                       196
Power On Hours:                     906
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   136
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      427
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               39 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               43 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

Here is the output of `smartctl -x /dev/nvme0` :

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-3-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 970 EVO 2TB
Serial Number:                      S464NB0KA03837J
Firmware Version:                   2B2QEXE7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            258,943,426,560 [258 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 5a81b50e6f
Local Time is:                      Mon Feb  3 10:42:30 2020 MET
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     82 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     82 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     6.20W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.30W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     2.10W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        39 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    170,671,351 [87.3 TB]
Data Units Written:                 6,787,156 [3.47 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 1,072,794,690
Host Write Commands:                62,980,162
Controller Busy Time:               1,480
Power Cycles:                       196
Power On Hours:                     906
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   136
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      427
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               39 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               42 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

---

I find such a test and the `no errors logged` message reassuring.

### question:

#### When should I become concerned?

In an ideal world I would prefer to have the SSD changed before it crashes unexpectedly. I heard a rumor that an SSD fails totally (not gradually, like rotating hard disk do). I am not a hardware guy at all.

What Linux command should I run (e.g. monthly) to assess the wear out of the the SSD NVME disk?

Comment: Could you show the output of `smartctl -d nvme -x /dev/nvme0`?

Comment: Done. Seems normal too.

Comment: Yes, the output of `-a` and `-x` is supposed to be identical on NVMe, I was wondering if it would show any more information on the logged errors.

Comment: While you got the official answer, I suspect the real answer is that we have no idea until the disk fails, as the kernel docs say: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/748009/59808 SSDs tend to fail "slowly, then all at once".

Answer (score 4):

Try `sudo nvme error-log /dev/nvme0` (requires the package `nvme-cli` to be installed via apt, synaptic or similar).

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of a SSD is usually limited by the number of writes the memory cells can handle.
The memory cells in an SSD/NVMe can only endure a limited number of write operations before they fail.

Generally the memory cells in solid state devices experience wear during each write operations and each memory cells tolerate only a limited (finite) number of overwrite passes. (This value is usually smaller and smaller as bits stored in each cells increase: SLC->MLC->TLC->QLC). Most solid state disks (SSD devices) report the overall health of the memory cells by various attributes.

You can use `smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1` to see the health information about your nvme disk.

The `percentage_used` shows the calculated number by disk manufacturer about disk lifespan. The `available_spare` parameter which indicates how many of the spare memory cells are available.
Unless the "available_spare" is down to 1% and the "percentage_used" is going up to 100% the SSD is still fully functional.

Once you reach those limits though, you should think about replacing the SSD. Another indicator is `Critical Warning` which should be always `0x00` check the [NVMe specification](https://nvmexpress.org/wp-content/uploads/NVM-Express-1_4-2019.06.10-Ratified.pdf) for other numbers.

Truncated example output of a failed/wearedout NVMe:

```
=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- available spare has fallen below threshold
- media has been placed in read only mode

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x09
Temperature:                        54 Celsius
Available Spare:                    0%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    3%
Data Units Read:                    152,049,475 [77.8 TB]
Data Units Written:                 123,071,212 [63.0 TB]
```

Example of a healthy NVMe:

```
=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        38 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    8,602,182 [4.40 TB]
Data Units Written:                 13,527,143 [6.92 TB]
```

Example of a NVMe that is has used some spares but is still healthy:

```
=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        45 Celsius
Available Spare:                    74%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    3%
Data Units Read:                    435,391,613 [222 TB]
Data Units Written:                 47,171,668 [24.1 TB]
```

Good reads:
[how-long-do-nvme-drives-last](https://macguided.ngontinh24.com/articles/how-long-do-nvme-drives-last)